# pycharm: somewhat to add % as an insert pair?

Tags: python, pycharm

Getting started with Django and notice when working with HTML in pycharm that I need to use % between two blocks when creating templates. Was wondering if anyone knew how to have the % character be an inserted pair when highlighting like I can with brackets or quotes.

Example: Highlight in an HTML document on pycharm the string 'block content' and

by SHIFT + % it'd become '% block content %'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pycharm this is called `Smart Keys`. You can configure them in `Settings/Preferences|Editor|General|Smart Keys`. This explained in detail in the [Documentation](http://%20https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/completing-punctuation.html).

There is a checkbox you can enable called

> Auto-insert closing }} and %} in Django templates

Sadly it seems it is not possible to configure this behavior for arbitrary charakters. Although, one could try to write a purpose-build plugin.